# Neo4j / Indexed property VS creating distinct nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Let's assume this use case:

"Get all passed events between `2013/05/12 20:00` to `2013/05/14 21:00`".

The first way to achieve this case in Neo4j would be to make the property indexed:
**Event(startAt: ..., endAt: ...)**       (`startAt` and `endAt` being indexed)

This would lead to scan all events having its properties corresponding to the actual query.

Other way that I've just read:

[image]

**Question is: Is node traversal far better in term of performance than dealing with indexed properties for dates in this case?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is node traversal far better (in a multilevel datetime index) in term of performance than dealing with indexed properties for dates in this case?

No, indexed properties for dates is more performant than traversals for this type of data structure.

Here is detailed example of using a hybrid approach. Consider the following subgraph, where the elipses indicate a continuing pattern in the graph.

[image: Multilevel Calendar Index]

Please take a look at https://gist.github.com/kbastani/8519557 for the full calendar Cypher scripts that get or create (merge) a multilevel datetime index. This data structure allows you to traverse from one date to another date to get a range of events for a time series. A combination of both indexed property matching and traversals is the best approach, and is performant when modeled correctly.

[image: Example Data Model for Time]

For example, consider the following Cypher query:

```
// What staff have been on the floor for 80 minutes or more on a specific day?
WITH { day: 18, month: 1, year: 2014 } as dayMap

// The dayMap field acts as a parameter for this script
MATCH (day:Day { day: dayMap.day, month: dayMap.month, year: dayMap.year }),
      (day)-[:FIRST|NEXT*]->(hours:Hour),
      (hours)<-[:BEGINS]-(shift:Event),
      (shift)<-[:WORKED]-(employee:Employee)

WITH shift, employee
ORDER BY shift.timestamp DESC

WITH employee, head(collect(shift)) as shift

MATCH (shift)<-[:CONTINUE*]-(shifts)

WITH employee.firstname as first_name, 
     employee.lastname as last_name, 
     SUM(shift.interval) as time_on_floor

// Only return results for staff on the floor more than 80 minutes
WHERE time_on_floor >= 80
RETURN first_name, last_name, time_on_floor
```

In this query we are asking the database "What staff have been on the floor for 80 continuous minutes or more on a specific day?" where shifts are broken up into 20 minute continuous intervals pointing to the next one in the series as CONTINUE or BREAK.

First you start with matching the day using the indexed properties. Then you scan the day's hours for connected events by traversing the datetime multilevel index. Then reverse the order of the events to get the most recent event in the series. Then traverse until a "BREAK" relationship is encountered. Finally, apply the condition of time_on_floor being greater or equal to 80 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

A better way of designing time line tree (especially in cases when you want to search between periods of intervals) :
[here](http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/modeling-multilevel-index-in-neoj4.html)

Cypher traversals to find the right event would be better if you are more interested in finding a range of events occurring between a time interval.

Neo4j stores node properties as a linkedlist. More info : [here](http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals) If you go through the neo4j storage architecture you will realize that creating unique relationshiptypes which will make your traversal even better performance wise.